# Rails 7 / Turbo Frames Streams Architecture

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hotwire-rails

I'm building a turn-based art generation game using Rails 7. Players take turns to construct a prompt that is then used to generate an artwork using Stable Diffusion. The game is mostly working, but I want to add real time features into it so that it feels more game like.

These are the models I have:

- Room.rb, where the games happen
- Game.rb, belongs_to a room
- Player.rb belongs_to room
- Prompt.rb, belongs_to player

Right now, I've loaded a lot of logic into the GamesController

You can kind of see it in action here: https://fresco.lol

I want Realtime actions for when:

- Players join a room (When two or more players have joined a room, they can start a game)
- When a game is started
- When a player is entering a prompt (streamed to other players that the player is typing)
- When a prompt is created
- When artwork is generated

Right now, the only part I've got working with Turbo Frames / Streams is the realtime action of players joining a room, but having trouble figuring out how it would work for the other specs. I am tempted to rewrite everything starting with basic rails scaffolding and then start building in the game logic.

How would you construct this game using rails scaffolding and Turbo frames and Turbo streams for the realtime events?

Right now, the only part I've got working with Turbo Frames / Streams is the realtime action of players joining a room, but having trouble figuring out how it would work for the other specs. This is because I have a lot of logic loaded into the RoomsController. I am tempted to rewrite everything starting with basic rails scaffolding and then start building in the game logic.